# .NET Random Class picking always 0 when range is 0 or 1

Tags: .net, random

I am writing a random question generator. I would like to pick one question from each section.

Random class with DateTime.Now.Milliseconds as seed value generates random numbers, if the range is greater than 2(0,2/2+). But, If I give a min of 0 and a max of 1 in the range, it always returns me 0.

Am I using it wrongly.

Please suggest if there are any other alternatives.

Thanks,
Mahesh

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You're calling [`Random.Next`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4.aspx), which returns a random integer more than or equal to the first parameter and less than, but not equal to, the second.
Specifically, you're asking for an integer in the range `[0, 1)`, which can only be zero.

If you're looking for an integer that is either `0` or `1`, you need to call `Random.Next(0, 2)`.

If you're looking for a real number between `0` and `1`, you need to call `Random.NextDouble`.

Comment: If you are converting the Java method Math.random, then you need to have two lines.  Random r = new Random(); r.NextDouble();

Answer (score 0):

Reading on MSDN ([Random.Next(int)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zd1bc8e5.aspx), [Random.Next(int, int)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4.aspx)) you will see that the upper bound is always exclusive. That is, to get a number between 0 and 1 (both inclusive) you can do:

```
Random prng = new Random();
Console.WriteLine(prng.Next(0, 2)); //2 because it is exclusive
```

Answer (score 0):

MSDN: Random.Next Method (Int32) Returns a nonnegative random number less than the specified maximum.
Use this.

```
Random random = new Random();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Genereted value:{0}", random.Next(2));
}
```